# Proving by induction $4^n < 5^n$ where $n > 0$

Tags: inequality, induction

I have done a few normal inductions (like divisibility and sums) and know a little bit about strong induction. I can't find any problem similar to this one and am struggling to understand any intuition that would make proving this statement any easier.

Here is how far I have gotten (not very much):

Base Case:

$4^1 < 5^1$

$4^2 < 5^2$

$16 < 25$

Induction:

$4^k < 5^k$

$4^{k+1} < 5^{k+1} = 4\times4^k < 5\times5^k$

I have no clue where to go or how to force the k+1 equation to somehow equate to the k equation.
Sorry if this has been asked before.
Thank you.

Comment: Notice that $4^{k+1}  = 4 \cdot 4^k < 4 \cdot 5^k$ by induction hypothesis. Can you continue from here?

Comment: this is quiet obvious. $4^{k+1}=4.4^k<4.5^k<5.5^k=5^{k+1}$

Comment: The last line is definitely not true!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the base case, directly checking the inequality
$$
4^1 < 5^1
$$
is enough.

Now, if for some positive integer $k$ we have
$$
4^{k} < 5^{k}, \quad \mbox{(*)}
$$
we have to infer from it
$$
\mbox{the desired inequality } 4^{k+1} < 5^{k+1}.
$$

To make this inference, write
$$
\begin{array}{llll}
& 4^{k+1} & \\
= & 4^{k} & 4^1 \\
< & 4^{k} & 5^1 \quad \mbox{(by the base case)}\\
< & 5^{k} & 5^1 \quad \mbox{(by (*))}\\
= & 5^{k+1}.
\end{array}
$$

(So, basically, the task is to construct a chain of inequalities that leads to the desired result and where each inequality follows from something that's already been proved.)

Comment: Thank you so much! I appreciate it a lot, the logic is simpler now that I look back on it.

Comment: Basically, I am using the following fact: if $a < b$ and $c > 0$, then $ac < bc$.  (In other words, the fact that the function $f(x) = cx$ is strictly increasing.)

Answer (score 0):

You can relate the inequality for $k+1$ to the one for $k$ like this

$$
4 \times 4^k < 5 \times 4^k < 5\times 5^k
$$

where the first inequality follows from the fact that $4a < 4a + a = 5a$ for any positive $a$ and the second inequality is your inequality for $k$ multiplied by $5$ on both sides.

Comment: I do not know why that took so long for me to get but apparently it need 4 cups of coffee and your comment lol. Thank you!

Comment: Perfectly normal for this to be a tortuous (and sometimes torturous:) path.  Consider: you are solving two problems at the same time; i.e., figuring out *what* sequence of statements will lead to the desired result, and figuring out how to *justify* each statement in that process.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

An elementary rule for inequalities, seen in middle school, asserts that, for *positive numbers*,
$$a<b\enspace\text{ and }\enspace a'<b'\implies aa'<bb'.$$