# Use mathematical induction to prove that for all natural numbers $4^n < 5^n$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

I'm stuck at the inductive step, which is $4^{k+1} < 5^{k+1}$ , where $k> 0$. Any help would be much appreciated on how to prove my inductive hypothesis.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Induction Proof $4^k < 5^k$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4057039/induction-proof-4k-5k)

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4056737/42969

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$$ 4^{k+1} = 4\cdot4^k < 4\cdot 5^k < 5\cdot5^k =5^{k+1}$$

Comment: Thanks! It understood it now.